# How to display a List with Spring <form:input>

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I'm trying to show a list of object 'Persona' using `<form:input>`.

This is my form

```
<form:form modelAttribute="persona">
     <c:forEach items="${personaList}" varStatus="contatore" var="persona">
         <form:input path="persona[${contatore.index}].id"/><br/>
          ...
      </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

This is the error I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'persona[0]' of bean class [com.springgestioneerrori.model.Persona]: Bean property 'persona[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:576)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:553)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:719)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.persona_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(persona_jsp.java:249)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.persona_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(persona_jsp.java:169)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.persona_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(persona_jsp.java:124)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.persona_jsp._jspService(persona_jsp.java:86)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:688)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:682)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:61)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:669)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:337)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:234)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:211)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTag.doEndTag(RenderTag.java:220)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.default_.template1_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(template1_jsp.java:284)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.default_.template1_jsp._jspService(template1_jsp.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:669)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:689)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:643)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:626)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

This is `Persona.class`:

```
    @Component
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class Persona implements Serializable{       

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5313982287615353480L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
        private int id; 

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "sesso")
        private Sesso sesso;    

        @Column(name="data_di_nascita", nullable=false, updatable=true)
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd")
        private Date dataDiNascita; 

        @Column(name="luogo_di_nascita", nullable=false, updatable=true)
        @Size(min=2, max=45)
        @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z09]*$.-_,")
        private String luogoDiNascita;  

        @Column(name="peso_in_kg", nullable=false, updatable=true)
        @Pattern(regexp="[0-9]")
        @Size(min=2,max=3)
        private int pesoInKg;

        @Column(name="altezza_in_cm", nullable=false, updatable=true)
        @Pattern(regexp="[0-9]")
        @Size(min=2,max=3)
        private int altezzaInCm;

        @Column(name="nome", nullable=false, updatable=true)
        @Size(min=1,max=45)
        @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z09]*$.-_,")    
        private String nome;

        @Column(name="cognome", nullable=false, updatable=true)
        @Size(min=1,max=45)
        @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z09]*$.-_,")    
        private String cognome;

        @Column(name="indirizzo", nullable=false, updatable=true)
        @Size(min=3,max=45)
        @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z09]*$.-_,")    
        private String indirizzo;

        public Persona() {      
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Sesso getSesso() {
            return sesso;
        }

        public void setSesso(Sesso sesso) {
            this.sesso = sesso;
        }

        public Date getDataDiNascita() {
            return dataDiNascita;
        }

        public void setDataDiNascita(Date dataDiNascita) {
            this.dataDiNascita = dataDiNascita;
        }

        public String getLuogoDiNascita() {
            return luogoDiNascita;
        }

        public void setLuogoDiNascita(String luogoDiNascita) {
            this.luogoDiNascita = luogoDiNascita;
        }

        public int getPesoInKg() {
            return pesoInKg;
        }

        public void setPesoInKg(int pesoInKg) {
            this.pesoInKg = pesoInKg;
        }

        public int getAltezzaInCm() {
            return altezzaInCm;
        }

        public void setAltezzaInCm(int altezzaInCm) {
            this.altezzaInCm = altezzaInCm;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public String getCognome() {
            return cognome;
        }

        public void setCognome(String cognome) {
            this.cognome = cognome;
        }

        public String getIndirizzo() {
            return indirizzo;
        }

        public void setIndirizzo(String indirizzo) {
            this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
        }

    }

Thank you
```

Comment: I think `persona[${contatore.index}].id` should be `persona.id` because persona is `contatore`'th item in the `personaList`

Comment: My problem is about what to write inside the PATH attribute of <form:input>. If I write ${persona.id}, I get the same error: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'persona' of bean class [com.springgestioneerrori.model.Persona]: Bean property 'persona' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: Please post `Persona` bean class.

Comment: I just added Persona.Class :D

Comment: `id` is the attribute of `persona` that you want in the path field. Just `id` should work, but all them would be referring to `id` of `persona` referred in the `modelAttribute` field.

Answer (score 2):

Use `${persona.id}` instead of `persona[${contatore.index}].id`

This line:

```
 <c:forEach items="${personaList}" varStatus="contatore" var="persona">
```

means "repeat the content for each item in `personaList`, while tracking the iteration status in `contatore` and assigning the current item into `persona`". So the framework has already done the assignment `persona = personaList[contatore.id]` for you.

Also, the whole expression to be evaluated needs to be inside the `${...}` markup.

Comment: My problem is about what to write inside the PATH attribute of  <form:input>. If I write ${persona.id}, I get the same error: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'persona' of bean class [com.springgestioneerrori.model.Persona]: Bean property 'persona' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="persona">
     <c:forEach items="${personaList}" varStatus="count" var="person">
         <input type="text" name="persona.persona[${count.index}].id" value="${person.id}"/><br/>

  </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```